# What config option sets DNS name to use in Eureka

Tags: netflix-eureka

I am trying to set an eip binding strategy in Eureka server.

Unfortunately i get an exception:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot get cnames bound to the region:txt.ap-southeast-2.null"

The exception is pretty clear about what's happening - it sets the DNS name to use to 'null'.

I have the following in my config:

```
eureka:
  server:
    domainName: mydomain.com
```

Obviously this doesn't seem to be enough.

The Eureka doc seems to suggest this is all i need -https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Deploying-Eureka-Servers-in-EC2#configuring-eips-using-dns

Unfortunately this doesn't work. Is there another config parameter i need?